# Open a modal view on tapping a uiscrollview that contains uiimageview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I need to open a modal view on taping the uiscrollview that contains a uiimage view. I handled the gesture and am getting the coordinates of the tapped point, but do not know how to trigger a new modal view from there. I used storyboard to create a new view which i need to open on tapping. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom segue that you can manually trigger in your code in the place where you receive your gesture recognition. Here is a [tutorial on creating custom segues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html).

You could also create a manual modal segue that is not connected to any specific action in your storyboard, but triggered manually in your code. You do this by ctrl+clicking from the view controller that you want to initiate the segue from and dragging over to the view controller of your modal view. Give the segue an identifier in your storyboard. Then you would manually perform this segue in your code where your gesture is received. Here is a [tutorial on how to do this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html).